# How can I process multiple Google Places API results after all the callbacks have completed?

Tags: javascript, callback, google-places-api

I have an `array` that contains location results from the Google Geocode and Places JavaScript API.

Any elements in this array from the Place results contain the `place_id` value which I'd like to utilise to get further basic information about that place.

The initial array (`uniqueGeoRes`) may contain up to 7 results.

I am confused between the Places API Service and Callback, and how to implement a callback when all of the elements of `uniqueGeoRes` have been checked for additional Places data.

For example, if all 7 elements of `uniqueGeoRes` have a `place_id` I need to use the Places Service to get additional information on each element.

The loop to do this is completing before the Places callbacks are complete because the outer function is not asynchronous.

I think a promise might have helped, but I'm limited to ES3. Here's what I have so far.
This doesn't give the expected results because by the time the callback has completed the value  `i` has already met that of `q`, even on the first callback.

I've gotten myself totally lost!

How can I ensure the Places callbacks are complete before doing anything with the newly populated `addrOutput` array?

```
var q;
q = 7;


// Set the size of the results array (q is hardcoded maximum value)
if (uniqueGeoRes.length < q) {
    q = uniqueGeoRes.length;
}
uniqueGeoRes.length = q;
var addrOutput = [];

//Check for additional Places data
function updatePlace(arr, callback1){
    
    console.log('asyncFunction has been called');
    console.log('processing: ', arr);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < q; i++) { // each element in the uniqueGeoRes array
    
        if (arr[i].source = 'Places API') {   
        // Append extra information from the Place look up on individual place_id

            console.log('Getting additional information for PLACES result: ' + arr[i].place_id);
            
            var request = { placeId: uniqueGeoRes[i].place_id, fields: ['address_component', 'formatted_address', 'geometry', 'name'] };
            service.getDetails(request, callback);
                
            function callback(place, status) {  // Get the additional place information.
                
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    
                    
                    addrOutput.push(place);
                    console.log ('Loop is ' + i + '/' + q + '. addrOutput length is now: ' + addrOutput.length);
                    
                    if (i === q) {
                        callback1()
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    console.warn ('Place Service Status is bad.');
                } 
                
            }
                
        } 
    }
    
};  

// Call when asyncFunction completes
function callback1(error) {
  if (!error) console.log('asyncFunction is complete');
}


updatePlace(uniqueGeoRes, callback1);
```

This is the current output

```
[Log] asyncFunction has been called (development, line 817)
[Log] processing:  – [Object, Object, Object, …] (7) (development, line 818)
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]Array (7)
[Log] Getting additional information for PLACES result: ChIJwSc0D-zih0gR2uOIFj2UCv8 (development, line 824)
[Log] Getting additional information for PLACES result: ChIJr_4dcTH9h0gRl1OqMr4OSec (development, line 824)
[Log] Getting additional information for PLACES result: ChIJ9wqvVQ7jh0gRPYUz575U0Bs (development, line 824)
[Log] Getting additional information for PLACES result: ChIJBw3rDLXih0gRivw-FONRgZU (development, line 824)
[Log] Getting additional information for PLACES result: ChIJ774cdbXih0gRwWCg-MxTKjs (development, line 824)
[Log] Getting additional information for PLACES result: ChIJwQnvs5Pih0gR125FEtKwli0 (development, line 824)
[Log] Getting additional information for PLACES result: ChIJXyhtsZPih0gRIZgUPLvv_Ws (development, line 824)
[Log] Loop is 7/7. addrOutput length is now: 1 (development, line 835)
[Log] asyncFunction is complete (development, line 854)
[Log] Loop is 7/7. addrOutput length is now: 2 (development, line 835)
[Log] asyncFunction is complete (development, line 854)
[Log] Loop is 7/7. addrOutput length is now: 3 (development, line 835)
[Log] asyncFunction is complete (development, line 854)
[Log] Loop is 7/7. addrOutput length is now: 4 (development, line 835)
[Log] asyncFunction is complete (development, line 854)
[Log] Loop is 7/7. addrOutput length is now: 5 (development, line 835)
[Log] asyncFunction is complete (development, line 854)
[Log] Loop is 7/7. addrOutput length is now: 6 (development, line 835)
[Log] asyncFunction is complete (development, line 854)
[Log] Loop is 7/7. addrOutput length is now: 7 (development, line 835)
[Log] asyncFunction is complete (development, line 854)
```

Answer (score 0):

forkJoin can help in this scenario. Using forkJoin, we can have collection of observables and callback function when all observables are completed. Below links may help with samples

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-c3f62b?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Similar functionality can be achieved using Promise.all

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thanks, is there an ES3 example of Promise All though?